# Is there Flow's version of flatMapIterable?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have started using Kotlin Flow. Now I'm struggling to map elements from a list, returned by api, one by one. Is there an operator available that does something like RxJava's `flatMapIterable`?

For example, when the Flow has an `ArrayList<T>`, then I want to make an operation on every element of that list, and get it as a new Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMapMerge` operator to achieve the desired result. You can convert a `Flow<List<T>>` to `Flow<T>` this way:

```
yourFlow.
   flatMapMerge { it.asFlow() }
```

This way you can further process the stream from every element of the initial list using the default Flow operators.

Here is the doc: [flatMapMerge](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html)